# capybara: within scope does not restrict actions to inside of that element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

There are multiple similar kind classes and buttons but I was trying to click on a button which is inside a particular class by using code

```
 within(first(locator, text: text))do
    scroll_to(first('button'))
    first('button').click
  end
```

from

```
   <div class="some parent class"> 
         <div class="some other class" id="1">
               <div class="class1">......</div>
               <div class="class2">......</div>
               <div class="class of button">......</div>
            </div>
       <div class="class used inside within" id="2">
           <div class="class1">......</div>
           <div class="class2">......</div>
           <div class="class of button">......</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

But when I run my above code then it clicks similar kind of button which is inside the `class some other class` and not used inside within. Any suggestion what should I do to make it work.

Also to check I have run `first(locator, text: text)` and path of found element is for the path of class `<div class="class used inside within" id="1">`

Comment: is `within('div#2.class_used_inside_within') do first('button').click end` working for you? just to try to catch where's the problem

Comment: Maybe scroll_to method is messing this up?

Comment: thanks guys for your suggestion, it was not the scroll_to function. It works fine. Infact i was using page.execute_script("$('button').click()") to click on the button in my code which seems to be not restricted to the class I have used inside within. But now i clicked with pure capbybara code without script and it click on correct button now. a stupid mistake on my side.sorry for that

Comment: @waqas, You could post this answer here and mark it as correct one. So we will close the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I get it working. Infact i was using page.execute_script("$('button').click()") to click on the button in my code which seems to be not restricted to particular class by using within. But now i clicked with pure capybara code without script and it clicks on correct button now